# AWS CLI "aws configure" doesn't switch me to a new account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am using a Windows 11 machine. I run `aws configure`, enter my access and secret keys, and am able to confirm that they are saved inside `~./aws/credentials.`

However, when I run `aws sts get-caller-identity`, it shows that I am still logged into my old account. What could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of agony, it turned out that AWS CLI takes the environment variables first, and not the `~./aws/credentials` config file. And since `aws configure` only updates said file, I was stuck updating something that was being overridden by default.

After deleting the environment variables starting with `AWS_`, everything works as expected.

Note that using profiles if you have your keys in your env will not work as expected either, and you will always be stuck on the profile configured in your environment variables.

Comment: Yes, the AWS CLI uses the boto3 AWS SDK for Python. Reference: [Credentials Chain — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html)